# How to define a custom keyPad in my App?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want define a custom keyboard in my App,When I  press one TabBar Item in my UITabBarController, then custom keyboard slide up， when I touch the the tabview, I hope the custom keyboard can slide down, But, Because the custom keyboard add in UITabBarController's view, and tableView add in UIViewController one of UITabBarController's  ViewController, they are not in the same Class, How can I define the Keyboard, and add to which view?

I want to do like this:
When Press tab bar Item keyboard slide up,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/66NDu.png

When touch tableview, keyboard slide down.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiHaR.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why are you declaring the custom keyboard in the `UITabBarController` class ? You can declare it in the view controller that is attached to that particular `tabBarItem`. If you add it to the that view controller, I am sure you can just make it `resignFirstResponder` or `removeFromSuperView` and manipulate it as you want.
2. Or you can just create a separate class for your `customKeyboard`, and add it along with your other classes. Simply include that class and create objects in other view controllers to manipulate them, and then `release` them. This is very easy and it is better programming compared to your approach, as at a later point of time, if you need to make changes or release 2.0 version of your app, it will come in handy and save some development time !

Comment: SUggest a custom class: make each class do one thing.

Comment: Thank you very much. Because I want to implement keyboard slide up when the method "tabBarController didSelectViewController: " in UITabBarControllerDelegate.

Comment: @Sam Niu Don't show the keyboard there. Show it in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear of your UIViewController.

Comment: Create a custom keyboard class.  In `tabBarController didSelectViewController` instantiate the custom keyboard class and use it.

Comment: Hi CocoaFu, I can create a custom keyboard class. but when in another class, I want the kayboard slide down, How I can do? Image like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/66NDu.png  and http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiHaR.png  they are in the same view.

Comment: @SamNiu You just need to create an object for the keyboardClass inside the class you want to use it .

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom UIView with your custom keyboard buttons.
UITextField and UITextView have a property called inputView. If you set your custom view to this, iOS automatically takes care of resignFirstResponder and becomesFirstResponder messages on the text field.

This is the easiest way to use a custom keyboard.

Comment: This is the best solution if you fit into two categories 1. Your input class is a subclass of UITextField/ UITextView 2. You do not have to support anything before iOS 3.2.

Comment: I'm using this approach, but if I create the variable for the custom UIView in my controller (where I also have the properties representing my UITextField declared), how do I get a reference to the UITextField from inside my keyboard class, so I can call insertText on it when the user taps one of my custom keys?

Comment: Delegates or blocks are the only way out.